# Find out which DBMS belongs the file

Tags: database, reverse-engineering

I've an application, that uses encrypted (txt) files to store data. After investigating the decompiled assembly I concluded that it's a file of some DBMS. So how can find out which DBMS is this application using to store it's data, so that I can attach that file to the correct DBMS.

This is little application and there is no license problem. I can just ask the owner to gimme the data, but just curious to solve this myself.

MORE INFO:

Platform is Windows, and after trying couple of decompilers I concluded that it WAS written in Visual C++. However I couldn't fully decompile this exe, otherwise I just could find out it from the source code.

Comment: What platform/language is the application?

Comment: The first few bytes of a file often specify a file format identifier ("type code"). Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas.

If opening the file in a HEX editor doesn't give you any information (like a magic identifier at the start of the file, which you can pop into google, then:

Use [the depends tool from microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738370%28WS.10%29.aspx) to grab a list of the DLLs being loaded by the application. Chances are whatever DBMS it's using is contained in an external library.

If the first two suggestions yield nothing, load the executable [into IDA pro freeware](http://85.17.92.154/files/idafree49.exe) and have a look at the code which is creating these files.

Comment: There are 3 files being used, and all three have different "first couple of bytes". So I think my conclusion that some DBMS is used may be wrong. I think developer just stored the file using some encryption format then. Any other ideas?

Comment: My third suggestion still applies, download IDA and locate the code that is doing the encryption. That's really the only option you have.